# Net use returns "System error 67 has occurred" when specify username/password

Tags: windows, powershell, samba, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried first to connect the remote samba shared folder (Linux) using explorer on a server(Windows server 2012r2)  and entered remote username and password. It works and I can see the remote files.

Then I tried to write a script in powershell.

```
$dest = '\\remote\shared'
$username = '.\username'
$password = 'password'
net use "$dest" $password /USER:$username
```

However it always gives the error of

```
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

But `net use $dest` doesn't give any error. `net use $dest /delete` doesn't return any error either.

Comment: Works fine for me. You sure the $Dest path and share are actually available and that you have permissions?

Comment: I found the issue, I need to change the user name from `.\username` (although it works when using file explorer and created confusion) to `remote\username`.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I didn't use the `.` as I needed a real account to test with, and I'm on a domain.  And yeah, you need to specify credentials that are known on the target machine, not the one you are running `net use` on.  :)

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of [Net use returns “System error 67 has occurred” when specify username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39856389/995714)